# after_create is not triggered in Observer after an activity is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

There is my Observer code:

```
class ActivityObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe PublicActivity::Activity

  def after_create(activity)
    if activity.trackable
      Something.create(trackable: trackable)
    end
  end
end
```

My spec is

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ActivityObserver do
  describe '#after_create' do
    it "should be triggered after an activity is created'" do
      activity = create(:activity)
      ActivityObserver.instance.should_receive(:after_create).with(activity)
    end
  end
end
```

But it did not pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move and edit this line

```
ActivityObserver.instance.should_receive(:after_create)
```

above

```
activity = create(:activity)
```

you are calling create before telling Rspec to look for the after_create call, that's probably why its failing

Comment: Thanks. but it said `expected: 1 time with any arguments, received: 2 times with any arguments`

Comment: what does create(:activity) actually do? is there source code for it that we can look at?